# Exception on creating a EDMX/DB-Schema using Entity Framework 4 using ContextBuilder with a generic class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, exception, .net-4.0-beta-2

I'm using the **Microsoft.Data.Entity.CTP** (in the Entity Framework CTP) under the .NET 4 framework to create the EDMX metadata from my C# classes to create a database schema.

I setup a simple model as such:

```
public class AModelContainer : ObjectContext
{
    public IObjectSet<RegularClass> RegularClasses { 
        get { return CreateObjectSet<RegularClass>(); }
    }
}
```

I follow the simple pattern of defining a new ContextBuilder based on my model.

```
var builder = new ContextBuilder<AModelContainer>();

using(var context = builder.Create(new SqlConnection(connString)))
{
    context.RegularClasses.AddObject(new RegularClass());

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

*This works fine*. **Until** I try to do something a little more complex...

I extend my model with a generic class

```
public class AModelContainer : ObjectContext
{
    public IObjectSet<SpecialClass<string>> SpecialClasses { 
        get { return CreateObjectSet<SpecialClass<string>>(); }
    }
}
```

Now on the save I get an **exception**:

> Mapping and metadata information could not be found for EntityType 'Prototype.SpecialClass`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'.

On this line in the *AModelContainer*:

```
return CreateObjectSet<SpecialClass<string>>();
```

The default constructor of my generic 'SpecialClass' does nothing at the moment, should it?

```
public class SpecialClass<T> 
{
    public SpecialClass()
    { }
}
```

Or is this an issue with the *ContextBuilder* not knowing what to do exactly, is there a way to use builder.ComplexType(), or other method to guide it?

Or the CTP can't deal with this scenario yet...

That "*`1*" after my class name also doesn't sit well with me in the exception...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use Generic classes as Entities with the EF (and by extension Code-Only) today.

This is a limitation of the Mapping capabilities between the CLR and the Conceptual Model.

Post Beta2 we added the ability to allow this sort of thing:

```
public class Entity<TKey>
{
   public TKey ID {get;set;}
}

public class Person: Entity<int>
{
   public string Firstname {get;set;}
   public string Surname {get;set;}
}
```

Where only `Person` is an 'Entity' in the EF's model, and the `ID` property from the base class shows up as a property of `Person`.

But there are no plans in .NET 4.0 / EF 4 to support mapping a generic class itself to an Entity in the model.

Hope this helps

Alex